# Authentication error when uploading file to firebase storage

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am uploading a small file to vuejs and Firebase storage using vuejs and I am constantly getting a `QUOTA_EXCEEDED` error. There is a extremely large no of calls to `https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=<SomeLongString>`.
I also see that the file has been uploaded successfully to firebase storage and there are no `denies` in firebase storage.
Needless to say that the application is still in development.

What am I missing?

**Request url:**

```
https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=<SomeLongString> 400
```

**Error response:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "QUOTA_EXCEEDED",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

**VueJs code snippet:**

```
    import 'firebase/storage';
    var metadata = {useVocabularyWhenFileIsTranscribed: true};
    const filepath=`1234567890/files/${uuid()}${validfiledata.name}`;
        
    //store file in firebase storage
    let storagereference = firebase.storage().ref();
    let uploadtask = await storagereference.child(filepath).put(validfiledata.rawFile, metadata);
    console.log(`uploadtask : ${JSON.stringify(uploadtask)}`);
 await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc('1234567890').set({
          files:
          {
            file:firebase.firestore().FieldValue.arrayUnion({metadata: metadata, path:filepath}),
            createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
          }
        }, { merge: true });
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by not awaiting on the firebase storage put.

**VueJs code snippet:**

```
  import 'firebase/storage';
    var metadata = {useVocabularyWhenFileIsTranscribed: true};
    const filepath=`1234567890/files/${uuid()}${validfiledata.name}`;
    let storagereference = firebase.storage().ref();
    let uploadtask = storagereference.child(filepath).put(validfiledata.rawFile, metadata);
```